# strange phenomenon when use QFile with character ~

Tags: qt4

i want to create a file in /home/username/
so i write some codes like this

```
    #define CONFIG_FILE_PATH "~/.config/xmlfile

    QFile file(CONFIG_FILE_PATH);
    if (!file.open(QFile:ReadOnly | QFile::Text))
    {
        if (!file.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text))
        {
        //print error message
        }
        else
        {
        //dosomething
        file.close();
        }
    }
```

but when i run the program, i cannot find "xmlfile"
i tried

```
    sudo find / -name *xmlfile*
```

but found nothing
and the program do not show any error messages.

is there some rules with the character ~ when using QFile?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience with `QFile` it doesn't like any 'special' characters within the file path such as tilde, you're best off using relative or full paths. If you use `QDir::homePath()` it'll return a string to the current user home directory (see the documentation here: [QDir special paths](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qdir.html#the-current-directory-and-other-special-paths).

Comment: Awesome, don't forget to accept the answer (the little tick).